# How to get playwrightUrl of Docker container for Playwright (needed to integrate Karate scripts)?

Tags: docker, ui-automation, karate, playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to execute the Karate script in `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic` Docker container.

I have exposed the port 5900 as shown below but not sure how to get the `playwrightUrl` for the container. Do I need to execute the `node server.js` inside it to get websocket endpoint?

```
docker run --name playwright -it --rm --ipc=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -u root -p 5900:5900  -v $(pwd):/src -v /home/Automation/:/root/.m2 mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic &
```

Comment: I don't know either. you seem to be evaluating or using karate, I think Ive made it clear this is advanced usage that we need help with - so if you are unable to do the necessary research and / or contribute code, please look for other options.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, you need to actually provide a working example of what you're trying to achieve.

What I understand from your question, is that you're trying to give the url for the tests from docker command in the terminal.

Since Playwright v1.13.0, there is a `baseURL` option available. You can utilise that in this way probably

In your `config.js` file, you can have this

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
  },
};
export default config;
```

In your command for running docker, you can then pass as

```
docker run --name playwright -it --rm --ipc=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -u root -p 5900:5900 -URL=whateverURLyouwant -v $(pwd):/src -v /home/Automation/:/root/.m2 mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic &
```

Also, one point I would like to mention is that, you should not use `root` user for your executions. Using `root` as user in docker is not a recommended practice. Instead use the `pwuser` that is already created by the given image.